# I am unable to get the starring of the film in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, querying

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT ?movieLink ?title ?starring ?releaseDate
WHERE {
    ?movieLink rdf:type db:Film;
               foaf:name ?title.
    OPTIONAL { ?movieLink prop:genre ?genreLink.
               ?genreLink rdfs:label ?genre.
               FILTER(lang(?genre) = 'en') }.
    OPTIONAL{ ?movieLink <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/releaseDate> ?releaseDate }.
    OPTIONAL{?starring <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/starring> ?releaseDate}.

    FILTER(lang(?title) = 'en')
    FILTER((?releaseDate >= '2016-01-01'^^xsd:date) && (?releaseDate < '2016-12-31'^^xsd:date))
}
ORDER BY DESC(?releaseDate)
LIMIT(15)
```

I am unable to get the starring for each film to display.
Is there a way i can use regex for the filter.

Comment: why should the starring of a film be connected to the release date of the film? doesn't make sense, right? The connection in DBpedia is from film to starring, thus, it should be `OPTIONAL{?movieLink <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/starring> ?starring}`

Comment: @AKSW Yes i agree i changed that to OPTIONAL{?starring <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/starring> ?starring}.
But i am not getting all the starring of the film. I would like to get all the starring of the film

Comment: ehm, what? I don't get what you're doing ... why `OPTIONAL{?starring <dbpedia.org/ontology/starring> ?starring}` now? I showed you the correct pattern, but you now connect starring with starring, makes no sense, right? ...  you have to connect film with starring ... why not copying the `OPTIONAL` pattern from my previous comment? That should work. And having a `LIMIT 15` indeed might not show all starrings of a film, especially since DBpedia endpoint shows only 10000 rows per request.

Comment: Thanks i found the solution

Comment: aha, and what was the solution?